# How to group fields with select option?

Tags: 7, entities

I just want to show the user to select any one of the group see the below image.

I am not sure which module i have to use.

[image]

Please suggest me how to do this ?

Comment: Do you mean you want different fields to display based on what the user selects for the radio button?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to have different fields displaying based on what the user selects for your radio buttons, use the http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields module.

There is documentation on how to use the module at http://drupal.org/node/1704126

To split the form into left and right sections you can use the http://drupal.org/project/ds module.

You can use the http://drupal.org/project/field_group module to group fields together, however to get the fields to indent underneath your radio button like in your image you will probably have to do some custom css and maybe a little custom themeing of the markup.

You should be able to get pretty close to what your image has though without custom work.